# Why does Mail generate random new messages in Lion?

Tags: email

Ever since upgrading to Lion on my 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo iMac, Apple's Mail sporadically generates random new mail messages, sometimes when mail isn't even running. And example of the latest contained the following text:

> As is and is and will will will will will and me and him and him and him and him him and him near his yes and that he is and he really didn't even see you as yet your letters (and me and yet very silly. And the people in England in the little well citizens in inhabitable monies that she made 13 276 did the phone will not have it in this. Can is been secretly he felt his ear as he leaves pretty drastically as easy as he steps in and see me in stress really hoping that he can see his risk as the rent is

No subject line and new addressees. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Dragon Express? There's a short discussion of this on the Apple.com forums. I've seen this problem, too, and by Th.e process of elimination have narrowed it down to Express. It seems to keep the mic open even when you aren't using it. You might also see random web searches with the same sort of garbled text.

My guess is that at some point the input buffer fills up and it launches either Mail or Safari with what it's heard.

Comment: That might be it. I do have Dragon Express and had it set up to start at login. I've disabled start at login so we'll see if that's the problem. (I was getting random safari pages as well.)